# Ubuntu shell script getting error

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

I am developing simple shell script which copy all my present directory files to **backup** directory which will be exist in present working directory. now i'm getting error when i pass more then one condition in **if**.

```
#!/bin/bash
filename=nx.pdf
for i in *;
 do
 echo $i;
 if [ $i == backup || $i == $filename ] ; then
    echo "Found backup."
 else
 echo "Part 2"
 cp -rf $i backup
 fi
 done
```

I am getting error

```
asd.sh: line 6: [: missing `]'
asd.sh: line 6: ==: command not found
Part 2
deployee.sh
asd.sh: line 6: [: missing `]'
asd.sh: line 6: ==: command not found
Part 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compare operator is = (as defined in POSIX). But == works on some shells as well.
Something like this should work:

```
if [ $i = backup ] || [ $i = $filename ] ; then
```

Answer (score 1):

You should quote $i in "". Otherwise you get syntax errors for filenames with blanks.

Comment: If i do 
{ if [ $i == backup ] ; then
    echo "Found"

then i'm not getting errors.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to use `||` and `&&` in conditions, you have to use the double square brackets:

```
if [[ $i == backup || $i == $filename ]] ; then
```